# I am trying to close a window in pyqt5 but it won't work

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

I am trying to restart the main Window to show the new set of data once the data is saved in secondary window. so basically I am trying to close the main window and open it again through the secondary window but it won't work, the previous Window won't close and it will open another window which is updated with new data. So is there any fix to this

```py
class secondAry(QWidget):
     #code
     def on_save(self):
        #code
        self.manapp = MainApp()
        print("CHECK")
        self.manapp.close()
        print("CHECK 2")
        self.manapp.show()
        self.close()

        sa_msg = QMessageBox()
        sa_msg.setIcon(QMessageBox.Information)
        sa_msg.setText("Saved")
        sa_msg.setWindowTitle("Information")
        sa_msg.exec_()
```

so when running the code, the program will print out "CHECK" but then it won't close the main window as intended, however it will print out "CHECK 2" which means that there is no error(?) and then it will open the new Window and close the secondary window and send out a message box. so  it means that the `self.manapp.close()` is not working while having no errors(?)

Comment: You're probably just creating a new window instead of closing the existing instance. Please provide a [mre].

Comment: Yes I am trying to close the old instance but it won't work

Comment: As said, [edit] your post and provide a MRE.